Is this Property Access Valid Syntax
I see in the MSDN documentation of init keyword, it has code example as below, from the url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init, from what I understand, the "YearOfBirth" in the beginning of the assignment "field = (YearOfBirth <= DateTime.Now.Year)" should be "value" keyword. Am I right? Or that is a new feature of a new C# version ? Thanks for your attention.
class Person_InitExampleFieldProperty
{
    public int YearOfBirth
    {
        get;
        init
        {
            field = (YearOfBirth <= DateTime.Now.Year)
                ? value
                : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), "Year of birth can't be in the future");
        }
    }
}


You're right, it should be value, as is, the test's result is always true since YearOfBirth is 0 when the test is executed

As noted right after the code sample, The field keyword is a preview feature in C# 13. So, the code is correct and works as expected, but only in C#13 with preview features enabled.

@Serg I don't think it does, the test should clearly check the new YearOfBirth value, not the old one

@vc74, yes, you are right. From a validation logic point of view it should be value there.

@Serg: field keyword? It could be something different: a private field with this name, (omitted by IcyBrk). Nothing prevents using this name. I followed the naming of the question and used this name in my answer. Of course, it works.

Yes, what you show does work, with value, but you also may find the alternative syntax more convenient and clear. Consider this very simplified example:
class InitOnlyDemo {
    internal InitOnlyDemo() { CaseB = 42; }
    int field = 0;
    internal int CaseA {
        get { return field; }
        init { field = value; } }
    internal int CaseB { get; init; }
    public int CaseC { get; private protected set; }
}

Your case is the property CaseA. With CaseB, you rely on automatically implemented getter and then init simply indicates “initialization-only” and leaves the initialization itself to the constructor. Finally, CaseC uses automatically implemented getter and setter and also demonstrates a way to prescribe different access modifiers for getters and setters.
